# Jquery, work with arrays

Tags: jquery

it's me again. How I can call data from defined array?

```
var myArray = new Array("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php", "http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/", "http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/");

$('img[src^="DATA FROM myArray"]').remove()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(myArray).each(function(idx,elem){
    /*idx is item index, elem is the item itself*/
    $('img[src^="'+elem+'"]').remove();
})
```

Comment: I believe this solution is the simpliest and the best one.

Comment: @Mister X: Don't forget to use the cleaner array literal notation in my answer.

Comment: Ow.. i'm not a jquery coder, just PHP. But what you mean with cleaner arrays?

Comment: @Mister X: `var array = [1, 2, 3]` instead of `var array = new Array(1, 2, 3)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select all that elements, independent from what you want to do with them, you could do:

```
var $elements = $();

for(var i = myArray.length;i--;) {
    $elements.add($('img[src^="' + myArray[i] + '"]'));
}
```

---

You should use array literals `[...]` instead of the array constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArray = [
    "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php",
    "http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/",
     "http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/"
];

$('img').filter(function() {
    var inArray = false;
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $.each(myArray, function() {
        if(src.indexOf(this) == 0)
            inArray = true;
    }
    return inArray;
}).remove()
```

Or you could just use regex:

```
$('img').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('src')
                  .match(/^http:\/\/(www|0|1)\.gravatar\.com\/avatar(\.php)?/i);
}).remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

> ```
> $('img[src^="' + myArray[1] + '"]').remove();
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's faster to fetch like this:

```
$("img[src]").filter(function() {
  return $.inArray($(this).attr("src"), myArray) != -1;
}).remove();
```

Comment: That doesn't do what was asked. The test is whether the `src` _starts_ with an array element, not _is_ an array element.

Answer (score 0):

[InArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) let's you get an the index of an item within an array. So:

```
myArray[$.inArray("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php",myArray)]
```